# laravel cache()-get() not working in commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

i have created following command in laravel using command `php artisan make:command RedisDataListener`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class RedisDataListener extends Command {
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'listen:subscribe';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Subscribe to redis channel for listening events';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle() {
        $value = cache()->has('tracking_application:mykey') ? cache()->get('tracking_application:mykey') : 'no';
        print_r(array(
            $value
        ));
    }
}
```

but when i'm using cache()->get('key') it is not working. Same function works fine when i use in controller.

i'm using redis as the cache server.
also tried with cache::get() but nothing happen.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i don't get any error.

this only prints no, when i use same function in any controller it shows what ever stored in that key.

Comment: Cache will work only for browser not for command line.

Comment: any reason to that?

Comment: @C2486 That's not true? 
@MuhammadMemon you can debug access to Redis by executing `redis-cli monitor` in a shell.

Comment: Thanks @Robert this really helped, for some reason it was not sending request to the redis server.